# PHP Data Structures (Java-like) Collections

Tags: php, data-structures

I'm wondering about the merits of creating a small library, probably for personal use which specifies a few data structures such as Linked Lists, Trees (Binary, AVL, etc...), Hash Lookup Tables, and the like.

Some of these would be built on top of the native PHP array, as it acts as many of these types, and some potentially wouldn't.

My question is really, would it make sense to build any of these classes - especially those which may not build upon the native array? I'm talking here about the computational practicality, and don't especially want to get into the dynamic vs. typed language argument (I'm still interested in hearing anything interesting and relevant on that topic as an aside).

Is it mad to build these (possibly more efficient, logically) data-structures using classes when we have a C implementation of a basic array?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already the http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php which may cover what you want but if building these would be interesting for you and improve your PHP/general coding skills then I think it would be a very good idea.

May also be a good library to release to a wider audience and something to put on your CV.

Comment: Yes, it is partly a learning experience, but as I mentioned to KingCrunch I'm not sure SPL is complete enough. I would happily release it if there was interest in it..

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at SPL

http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php

and read Matthew Turland's [New Spl Features in PHP 5.3](http://matthewturland.com/2010/05/20/new-spl-features-in-php-5-3/) for a discussion of those data structures.

Comment: I'm aware of SPL, although it has more data-structures than I remember. I would use those where possible, and implement those interfaces, but it doesn't seem to offer a complete library (for most purposes I concede it is sufficient).

Comment: Its trying to get a complete library for several years, so no one will know, when (or even if) this will happen one day ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer but this this would help someone looking for PHP data structures. PHP 7 introduces an extension called `ds` providing specialized data structures as an alternative to the array.

The `ds`,

- uses the `Ds\` namespace.
- has 3 interfaces namely,`Collection`, `Sequence` and `Hashable`.
- has 8 classes namely, `Vector`, `Deque`,`Queue`, `PriorityQueue`, `Map`, `Set`, `Stack`, and `Pair`.

For more information checkout the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ds.php) and also [This blog post](https://medium.com/@rtheunissen/efficient-data-structures-for-php-7-9dda7af674cd#.yqq72xmv1) has some awesome information including benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into performance, you may create a php module (like SPL) that gives access to these structures (as they are already implemented in C).

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that, the only problem is that it wouldn't be as easy to set up, especially for shared-hosts or other similar environments. I might look into it though