# Side effects of PHP's serialize as hash function

Tags: php, serialization, hashmap, hash-function

I'm looking to create a sort of `HashMap` class in PHP. For the sake of being able to build upon PHP's associative array functionality, I have a hash function, which should be able to take any variable (primitive or object) and turn it into a string for use as an array key.

For this hash function, I am thinking of using `serialize()`, but I noticed that PHP calls `__sleep()` on an object when that function is called. I'm assuming this could be problematic. Am I right?

If so, what can I use to get a hash of either a primitive data type or of an object? I did look at `spl_object_hash()`, but its results seem less than unique, as it uses reference locations, which appear to be reused?

Any thoughts? Thanks

**Update:** If anyone's interested, this is (roughly speaking) what I ended up with. The Collection interface can be ignored. Any improvements welcome, of course. *Oh, and there isn't a remove method yet.*

```
<?php

include_once 'Collection.php';

class HashMap implements Collection {

    private $data;
    private $hashes;

    public static function createEmpty() {
        return new HashMap();
    }
    public function __construct() {

        $this->data = new \SplObjectStorage();
        $this->hashes = array();
    }

    public function add($key, $value) {
        // var_dump($this->hash($key));
        $this->data->offsetSet($this->hash($key), $value);
    }

    private function hash($key) {
        if (!is_object($key)) {
            if (isset($this->hashes[$key])) {
                return $this->hashes[$key];
            } else {
                $obj = new PrimitiveAsObject(serialize($key));
                return ($this->hashes[$key] = $obj);
            }
        } else {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    public function get($key) {
        $key = $this->hash($key);

        if ($this->data->contains($key)) {
            return $this->data->offsetGet($key);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
class PrimitiveAsObject {
    private $val;
    public function __construct($v) {
        $this->val = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: isnt associative array already a hash map?

Comment: @jon_darkstar Yes, but it doesn't allow using objects as keys, which is something I need.

Comment: A serialized object as a key... :) wow, can you say what you're using that for, sounds amazing.

Comment: @markus It's primarily just a learning experience, but I'm looking into making a PHP collections library - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246262/php-data-structures-java-like-collections . It's not important that a key is a serialized object, just an unique hash of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mentioned that you're trying to use objects as keys in a hash, to store additional data.

The standard-in-PHP-5.3 [SPL Object Storage](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) class was designed for this use case, though it's kind of funky to use.  It can behave as an array, thankfully.

Now, it can only be used to store actual objects, not primitives.  This may pose a problem for your use case, but it's probably the best thing you've got for storage of objects as keys.

Comment: What exactly is funky about it?

Comment: The non-array based attach/contains/detach methods just strike me as *weird*, that's all.

Comment: That sounds quite good; I vaguely remember looking at this a while ago now. I agree on its funkiness - I'd probably put a wrapper class if it didn't impact performance too much.

Comment: Well, that's what `ArrayAccess` is for :)

Comment: That seems to work exactly as hoped. I've added the code into the post. Now to test..

Answer (score 2):

Objects as keys: [SplObjectStorage](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php)

Answer (score -2):

You can hash with `md5`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

But of course you need a reliable and unique `toString` for objects involved.

Comment: I need to be able to get the hash of any object, not just a string.

Comment: I wouldn't want to rely on any object's implementation of `toString()`, as I wouldn't know where these objects are coming from.

Comment: i didnt necessarily mean the objects `toString` but some means, likely an outside function.  most hash functions deal with strings